# db2RemStgManager analyse error based on error code

Tags: amazon-s3, db2

I am using a shell script to put a file in object storage. For this I am using;

```
db2RemStgManager S3 put
```

For now I am deliberately providing wrong creds.

I want to log a different error message if authentication failed. Currenlty when I log what the above command returns I see:

```
Error code: 251
Error message:
Recovery mode detected. Local diag path = |/tmp/a|. szICCPath = |/opt/ibm/db2/V11.1.0.0/lib64|.
```

From what I understand is 251 error code signifies shell's writing error. How can we check for authentication errors? when I look at /tmp/a/db2diag.log I can't see any specific authentication error message.

Answer (score 1):

To my knowledge, db2RemStgManager is not an IBM-supported command. It ships as a tool with Db2 to interface with Cloud Object Storage, but it is not documented. Because it is only a tool, there is nothing in the Db2 diagnostic logs. Typically, only the Db2 engine writes to it.

In summary, I recommend either the [official AWS CLI](https://github.com/aws/aws-cli) or one of the many other clients or libraries to work with S3-compatible storage services. Depending on the tool or library, there are all kinds of detailed error messages.